# Adding an External JAR and all its Dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies

I am trying to add a single external JAR file to my Eclipse path to make it able to perform a needed function. I have attempted to load in the project through Maven in hopes that it would gather all needed dependencies, but it still gives me an error.

Is there an easy way to make one single call to the internet to download all necessary dependencies for an External JAR (and all their dependencies, etc, etc)?

Mind you, this code is a very specific, one-time implementation that does not need to be exported or run on any other machine. Even if the program I'm writing will not ever work as a JAR on it's own, that's okay. I just need a quick and easy way to get all my dependencies in one shot.

Comment: Was the external JAR built with Maven?? Does it declares what dependencies does it need ??

Comment: If it was or does, I have no clue how to see it. I've tried adding about 50 other jars and none of them fix the error. How would you go about finding what dependencies are declared? I am not an experienced coder.

Comment: Many libraries that were built with maven, have their pom XML file inside the JAR... at META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artefactId> ... such pom file should declare its own dependencies...